# What (define (p) (p)) does?

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

I'm reading the "Structure and interpretation of computer programs" 2nd edition in the exercise 1.5, I found a combination that I didn't understand what it does exactly `(define (p) (p))`.

When I called the procedure `(p)` I had the cursor blinking in the next line without the ability to write anything .

```
(define (p) (p))
(p)
```

I don't know what to expect from this procedure because I defined it by itself.

Comment: Hmm, what could running the expression `(p)` do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`p` is a procedure with no parameters. Its body is `(p)`. In Scheme, we call procedures by surrounding them in brackets together with their arguments. Given that `p` doesn't have parameters, `(p)` simply calls `p`. Which calls `p`. Which calls `p`... and so on. So what does it do? an infinite loop! and that is all.

Answer (score 2):

```
(define (p) (p))
(p)
```

This is syntactic sugar for this

```
(define p (lamnda () (p))
(p)
```

After you deepen SICP you will learn that this infinite recursion can also be done so:

```
((lambda(s) (s s))
 (lambda(s) (display ".") (s s)))
```